# How to implement ActiveRecord has_many through polymorphic association with different source types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, belongs-to, polymorphism

I have 3 Models: Vote, Student and Teacher. A Student can give a vote for either another student or a teacher. Previously a student could only give a vote for one student or one teacher. But now i want to have the option to vote for multiple students and teachers. The vote model additionaly stores a category_id and a rating, so that you can give different rated votes in the same category. For the polymorphic many-to-many relation between vote and Teacher/Student i use a fourth model called SingelVotedRelation, which has the attributes vote_id, voted_id and voted_type.

Now i want to have the ability to call vote.voted and get a collection of the voted persons (student or teacher) without having to mess around manually with the SingleVotedRelation Table:

```
has_many :voted, through: :single_voted_relations
```

But i get error messages when i tried this. My working Vote Model looks like this:

```
belongs_to :voter, class_name: "Student"
has_many :single_voted_relations
has_many :voted_students, through: :single_voted_relations, source_type: "Student", source: :voted
has_many :voted_teachers, through: :single_voted_relations, source_type: "Teacher", source: :voted
```

SingleVotedRelation looks like this:

```
belongs_to :vote
belongs_to :voted, polymorphic: true
```

Student:

```
has_many :given_votes, class_name: "Vote", foreign_key: "voter_id"
has_many :single_voted_relations, class_name: "SingleVotedRelation", as: :voted # polymorphic
has_many :achieved_votes, source: :vote, through: :single_voted_relations
```

Teacher:

```
has_many :single_voted_relations, class_name: "SingleVotedRelation", as: :voted # polymorphic
has_many :achieved_votes, source: :vote, through: :single_voted_relations
```

I basically just want to join the voted_students and voted_teachers relations from the Vote-Model into one voted relation, which contains the students and also the teachers.

This may be too complicated and there could be a smarter way to achieve my goal.
Is it even possible to have different source types?

Help is appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Please always include the exact error message in the question.